# nvd3 + discreteBarChart + add a line to chart

Tags: nvd3.js

working with discreteBarChart in nvd3 here is the basic example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zH7xp/)

I have created this bar chart and I have got my data that feeds it to look like this as is required:

```
var data = [
  {
    key: "KPI_NAME",
    values: [
      { 
        "label" : "A" ,
        "value" : -29.765957771107,
          "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "B" , 
        "value" : 0,
          "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "C" , 
        "value" : 32.807804682612,
          "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "D" , 
        "value" : 196.45946739256,
       "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "E" ,
        "value" : 0.19434030906893,
       "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "F" , 
        "value" : -98.079782601442,
       "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "G" , 
        "value" : -13.925743130903,
       "series" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "H" , 
        "value" : -5.138732287,
       "series" : 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

see the jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zH7xp/4/) -> this is with the series added "series: 0" to my data object. This is just how I am creating my object and does not affect the graph.

now i have added another series to my data feed  and what i am trying to do is have a constant line in the graph but i get the following in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zH7xp/6/)(this is with the second series added in my data object)

Is there away I can get the second series to be a line so I would have a constant line accross the top with value 98?

Note: My data that feeds this graph could possibly be formatted better but I am just try to reuse what I already have.

Comment: Maybe a [line plus bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) would be more suitable for you?

Comment: @Lars tks, but that has date on the x-axis, i was trying to use this model as it has labels on the x-axis

Comment: That's not hardcoded into the chart type, that's just how you set up the axis. You should be able to use the line plus bar chart with labels just as well.

Comment: @Lars, tks I'll explore that but I'd still like to see if it can be done here.

Comment: @Lars have explored that and am having issues.advice appreciated, posted [Q here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464727/nvd3-lineplusbarchart-allign-axises)