# nvd3 + lineplusbarchart + allign axises

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

not sure if I am going about this the right way but here goes...

So i have the this example [see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GgBww/6/)
using lineplusbarchart and i am building on it from this question i posted here:
[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391330/nvd3-discretebarchart-add-a-line-to-chart?noredirect=1#comment34041862_22391330)

I have edited the lineplusbarchart to show the labels on the xaxis:

```
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
  var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
          return dx;
      })
      .showMaxMin(false);
```

but i am still having a couple of issues to get what i want...

1 -> 
 how can i make the y1 and y2 axis be alligned? (ideally it would be good if there was only one axis)

2 -> 
 how do i remove the y2 axis? ([soution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075708/nvd3-d3-js-how-to-remove-y2-axis) but this does not work as I then want the 2 axis aligned)

3 -> 
 how do i make the thickness of the barchart part for label1 and label5 to be the same thickness as the others(lable2,3 and 4)?

Answer (score 3):

hope this helps:

1. you can use `chart.lines.forceY()` to set a range.  To make it
   work with dynamic values I'd suggest to find the overall max value of the attached data
   and use it for the bar and the lines. Eg:

   ```
   var maxValue = d3.max(d3.entries(testdata), function(d) {
           return d3.max(d3.entries(d.value.values), function(e) {
               return e.value.y;
           });
       }),
       minValue = 0;

   chart.bars.forceY([minValue, maxValue]);
   chart.lines.forceY([minValue, maxValue]);
   ```
2. Your posted solution is exactly what I would do too.
3. Remove `padData()`

Comment: tks won't use the max/min for this model,but good to know. and removing padData() looks better. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/GgBww/10/). still room for improvement->  1  the legend (remove rightAxis/leftAxis)  2  make the line chart go all the way to the yaxis